# Combine SELECTCOLUMNS and ORDER BY in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

This works, it selects multiple columns:

```
evaluate SELECTCOLUMNS(branches,
         "The branch code", branches[code], 
           "The branch name", branches[name], 
           "The branch city", branches[city])
```

This also works:

```
evaluate branches
    order by branches[name]
    start at "Co"
```

But if I want to combine the two, I get an error:

```
evaluate ( SELECTCOLUMNS ( branches,
    "The branch code", branches[code],
    "The branch name", branches[name],
    "The branch city", branches[city]) )
    order by branches[name]
    start at "Co"
```

> A single value for column 'name' in table 'branches' cannot be
> determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column
> that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as
> min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

The error talks about aggregation, but I don't need to aggregate. What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function SELECTCOLUMNS returns a table, and ORDER BY refers to this new table, not to the original table "branches". Since new table does not contain field [name], you get the error. To fix it, simply refer to the fields in the new table:

```
EVALUATE
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    branches,
    "The branch code", branches[code],
    "The branch name", branches[name],
    "The branch city", branches[city]
)
ORDER BY [The branch name]
START AT "Co"
```